# Radio buttons inside AlertDialog saving to Firebase with different errors

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, radio-button, android-alertdialog

I am working with an Uber clone tutorial and trying to set car type in a layout when updating driver info.  Everything else works except the radio button part.

I tried the following but only got the following errors:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioGroup.check(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at DriverHome.showDialogUpdateInfo(DriverHome.java:783)
    at DriverHome.onNavigationItemSelected(DriverHome.java:771)
```

**layout_update_info**

```
...

<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/RydeX"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="UberX"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/RydeVan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="UberBlack"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/RydeSUV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="UberXL"/>

    </RadioGroup>
....
```

**DriverHome.java**

```
public class DriverHome extends AppCompatActivity {

   private RadioGroup radioGroup;
   String service;
   private String userID;
   private DatabaseReference driverDB;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_home);

     ...

   }

   @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
   @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
   @Override
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
   int id = item.getItemId();

   if (id == R.id.nav_update_info) {
     showDialogUpdateInfo();
   }

   DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
   drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
   return true;
   }

}


private void showDialogUpdateInfo() {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(DriverHome.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("UPDATE INFORMATION");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Please fill in all information");

    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View layout_pwd = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_update_info, null);

    final MaterialEditText editName = (MaterialEditText)layout_pwd.findViewById(R.id.editName);
    final MaterialEditText editPhone = (MaterialEditText)layout_pwd.findViewById(R.id.editPhone);
    final ImageView image_upload = (ImageView) layout_pwd.findViewById(R.id.image_upload);

    saveUserInfo();

    image_upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            chooseImage();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setView(layout_pwd);

    //Set Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("UPDATE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            final SpotsDialog waitingDialog = new SpotsDialog(DriverHome.this);
            waitingDialog.show();

            String name = editName.getText().toString();
            String phone = editPhone.getText().toString();

            Map<String, Object> updateInfo = new HashMap<>();

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                updateInfo.put("name", name);
            }

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)) {
                updateInfo.put("phone", phone);
            }


            // user_driver.tbl = "Users/Drivers"
            DatabaseReference driverInformation = FirebaseDatabase
                    .getInstance().getReference(Common
                            .user_driver_tbl);
            driverInformation.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                    .getCurrentUser().getUid())
                    .updateChildren(updateInfo)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(DriverHome.this,
                                        "Information Updated!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(DriverHome.this,
                                        "Information Update Failed!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            waitingDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

            getUserInfo();
        }

    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}


private void saveUserInfo() {

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    radioGroup.check(R.id.UberX);

    int selectId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    final RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectId);

    if (radioButton.getText() == null) {
        return;
    }

    service = radioButton.getText().toString();

    Map updateInfo = new HashMap();
    updateInfo.put("service", service);
}


private void getUserInfo() {

    driverDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0){
                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                if(map.get("service")!=null){
                    service = map.get("service").toString();
                    switch (service){
                        case"RydeX":
                            radioGroup.check(R.id.UberX);
                            break;
                        case"RydeVan":
                            radioGroup.check(R.id.UberBlack);
                            break;
                        case"RydeSUV":
                            radioGroup.check(R.id.UberXL);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });

}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

What I am trying to do is save the information to Firebase database:
name, phone, image and Type of Car the driver has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simply a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

**Problem**
your `RadioGroup` is part of `AlertDialog` not `DriverHome` Activity. so the line below will return `null`.

> radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

**Solution**

You should get `RadioGroup` from its parent container which is `AlertDialog`. and do same for `RadioButton` although you can also get `RadioButton` from `RadioGroup` cause its the parent of all `RadioButton`.

```
radioGroup = (RadioGroup)layout_pwd.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
```

Comment: I tried putting the contents of saveUserInfo() into AlertDialog and got same error.

Comment: You have to use `layout_pwd.findViewById()` not `findViewById()` as i said in my answer.

Comment: I just tried that and got error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioGroup.check(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.devhopes.rydedriver.DriverHome.showDialogUpdateInfo(DriverHome.java:783)
                                                                           at com.devhopes.rydedriver.DriverHome.onNavigationItemSelected(DriverHome.java:771)

Comment: line783:  alertDialog.setTitle("UPDATE INFORMATION");

Comment: line 771; if (id == R.id.nav_update_info) {

            showDialogUpdateInfo()

Comment: I also updated this line final RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)layout_pwd.findViewById(selectId); and it showed the Dialog but it didn't update to Firebase => service: "UberX"